# jQuery each method wont select appended HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a map and an array of markers. I would like for the users to be able to click on a button that is included in an appended HTML that is added to a `<p>` with a class of side. The below code is what I have and it works for the buttons above the map which are just a test for code right now.

However, I would like the eye button on the sidebar to act like the buttons above.

I have tried to use `$('#find').each`, but it does't work.

Will the each method not work with appended HTML?

I have found that this works for the appended HTML, however it wont run the marker click. I have this assigned to the eye buttons at this time:

```
$(document).on('click', '#find', function(i) {
 alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
      google.maps.event.trigger(markers[i], 'click');
     });
```

You can see my code at work here: https://ddtech.live/test/

Disclaimer: This is just a hobby of mine and still learning.

HTML

```
<p class="side"></p>
```

JS

```
 var markers = [];
        $('#btn button').each(function(i,e) {
          $(e).click(function(i,e) {  
           return function(e) {     
              google.maps.event.trigger(markers[i], 'click');
            }
          }(i));
        });


    var status = '<span style ="float: right"><button id="find" class="zoombtn2" onclick=""><i class="fas 
fa-eye"></i></button></span>'

     var name = markerData.first + " " + markerData.last;
     var str = name.toLowerCase().replace(/\b[a-z]/g, function(letter) {
        return letter.toUpperCase();
      });

 $(document).ready(function() {
      $('p.side').append('<div class="boxed">' + str + status + '</div>');
       });
```

Comment: `$(e).click(function(i,e) { ` <-- makes no sense, `i` is not the index

Comment: `$('#find').each` should only ever iterate over a single element, as ids are expected to be unique, thus the usage of `each()` there doesn't make sense.

Comment: Have you guys went to my site and seen the example of the buttons above and them working? https://ddtech.live/t is the working example I pulled from jsfiddle.

Comment: @ScottJ A question is expected to be self contained and not rely on external links to demonstrate the issue.  Links can become broken, or fixed, in which case the question becomes unless to future readers.

Comment: Understood, just trying to provide an answer to your answer as to it not making sense. It works, I am just trying to figure out how to implement it in my use case and I wanted you to see that the each() works.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `$('#find').each` as `#find` is an id. You can only use an id for one element per page. Assuming that the indices of your buttons correctly correlate with the google maps marker you could use this code:

```
$('.boxed button').each(function(i,e) {
  $(e).click(function(i,e) {
    return function(e) {
      google.maps.event.trigger(markers[i], 'click');
    }
  }(i));
});
```

You may have better results in assigning a data attribute to each button and using this to select the correct marker: `<button data-id="someid"></button>`

And in your each function you would select the data attribute with: `$(this).data("id")`

Comment: Thank you for your response, I tried the .boxed button and still did not work. The issue is and I have confirmed with console.log(e) that when I try to add anything as the element that is inside of the appended HTML, the each method will not find it. I know someone stated above that links can be broken, but my page is currently up and running. If you look at it, the buttons above the map work, but the ones to the side in the eye do not. The buttons above are using the #btn button in the each, but they are within the HTML of the page and not pushed into the p by jQuery or JS.

Comment: Where are you including your jQuery? I have tried adding the code snippet to your page in the browser console and the map pins relocate when clicked.

Comment: The jQuery is at line 1173

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using the below. Thanks again for those that answered.

```
function clickLatLng() {
  [...document.querySelectorAll('.boxed')].map((el, i) => {
    el.addEventListener('click', () => {
      map.panTo(markers[i].getPosition());
      map.setZoom(8);
    });
  });
}

side_bar_html += '<div class="boxed">' + str + location + live + '</div>';
//  put the assembled side_bar_html contents into the side_bar div
document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = side_bar_html;
```

Along with this as my button:

```
var location = '<button class="zoombtn" onclick="clickLatLng()"><i class="e70-5 x-icon" aria-hidden="true" data-x-icon-o=""></i></button>'
```